# VBA - Excel : If value What parameter in Find(What:="value") doesn't exists in a sheet for all the IDs

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with VBA for Excel.

I want to search for a specific value(for a specific ID) in a column of a sheet and pass the value in another table row (of that ID).    What happens If the value in the What:="value" parameter of the Find() method doesn't exists for all the IDs in the column?

If the ID (of the first sheet) doesn't have that value I dont want to pass any value to the other sheet (of that ID).I want to set a "#N/A" value instead. In fact it passes the value of the predecessor ID.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I use this technique for my `VLOOKUP` formulas which is just basic Excel and not VBA.

Say we have a simple two column table with ID in Column A, Values in Column B in Sheet 1 and we are looking up ID in Sheet 2.

```
= IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet1!A1:B100,2,FALSE)),"NA", VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet1!A1:B100,2,FALSE))
```

So do the lookup if you cannot find ID, then ISERROR is true and set NA, else get lookup value.

Such a construct may work in your case.

**EXTENSION**

**DATA**

Sheet looking like this, with ID in A1. So ID 3 is missing.

> ID    KEY
>
> 1 100
>
> 2 200
>
> 4 400

**CODE**

I have written two procedures. `findme` two searches for ID = 2 and 3, and `findcode` function looks up ID and then looks in next column offset 1 to find the value. I am getting back the error codes when search for 3 which is not in your list.

```
Sub findme()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Dim y As Variant

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A100")

    ' Example look for 2 - get 200
    i = 2
    y = findcode(CStr(i), rng)

    MsgBox ("id=" & CStr(i) & ". y = " & CStr(y))

    ' Look for 3 it should fail
    i = 3
    y = findcode(CStr(i), rng)

    MsgBox ("id=" & CStr(i) & ". y = " & CStr(y))

End Sub

Public Function findcode(i As String, rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim x As Variant

    Set x = rng.Find(What:=CStr(i), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False)

    If x Is Nothing Then
         i = CInt(CVErr(xlErrNA))
         findcode = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    Else
         findcode = x.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End If
End Function
```

So msgbox shows id = 2, y = 200 and then error code on second run.

Comment: I have chosen a different type of  declaration. It would change the whole logic.

i don't know how to implement the line of code. I'm a novice.

Comment: Agreed. I was just saying - do the search and then error trap with an IF statement, so IF iserror(myfindval) THEN set to NA or predecessor NA if it exists (ie not error on first one) ELSE place myfindval. I was also showing that you could do this with a VLOOKUP on the sheet and not resort to VBA.

Comment: Thank you, micstr, for the help.
I tried the If-Else statement. 
In the case that doesn't find the value, it passes the value of the of the predecessor Find. :(

Comment: Maybe I need to  explain myself better. I want  the Find() to find the value set on the what:="value" parameter. If it finds it ,I should get the value of its offset.In some cases(for some IDs), the value isn't written at all, so it can't find the offset and can't do nothing. I guess it goes in error.